# Blog Engine as a virtual directory and Umbraco application as parent application is causing the below error

Tags: razor, iis-6, umbraco, virtual-directory, blogengine.net

Parent application built using Umbraco 4.9.0.
Child application built using Blog Engine 2.8.

Am hosting this on IIS6, and am loading the website, my parent application is loading good but my blog is not loading and it is throwing the below error.

Server error in '\blog' Application.
Runtime error

I couldn't view the description of the error even after i make the customerror to "RemoteOnly"

But below is the error from Event Viewer.

Exception information:
    Exception type: HttpException
    Exception message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

AM very sure the parent application is inheriting and causing the above error, but i could fix it :( please help!

Your help is very much appreciated by this lone fighter.

Comment: Have you added the blog directory to the list of URLs to exclude in the Umbraco web.config?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you will need to do is to tell Umbraco to ignore the /blog url.  That way it won't try to process that route.

NOTE:

To do that find the "umbracoReservedPaths" key in the appSettings (in the web.config file).  In the value add ",~/blog" to the end of the other paths.

Also, remember that virtual directories inherit the web.config settings from the website they are in.  So you may need to add some 's to the web.config for BlogEngine to remove Umbraco things that it cannot or will not use.

Are they both running the same version of .net?

Comment: Concerning the .net version: both BlogEngine.Net and Umbraco use both .Net 4 since a few years.

Comment: Thanks Beaver, Could you please help me with how to tell Umbraco to ignore /blog URL? And yes i added the remove tags in BlogEngine web.config to not inherit from Umbraco web.config. 

Yes both the application is running on same .net framework of 4.0.

Comment: Added how to do that to my answer

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the following link for the answer of this question:

[Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, or one of its dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21375191/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-web-webpages-razor-version-2-0-0-0-cul)